# print output into a tkinter gui getting error

Tags: python, tkinter

This is my first time trying to use tkinter (kept getting warned there are better ways :P )  and my goal for the guid is to type out a table name in the gui and when clicking generate report button it prints the table in the output label (answer label).  I am getting the error when clicking on report and can't find what I am doing wrong.  Error is at the bottom.  This is a test system so no user information is being released.

```
    from __future__ import print_function
    from ast import Lambda
    import sqlalchemy as sa
    import pandas as pd
    import tkinter as tk
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import ImageTk, Image

    server = 'ABQSQ03t'
    username = 'TECO//AAPWP'
    password = 'Lil1jude1@#'
    timeout = '60'
    database = 'NMGC_PIM_DEV'
    driver = 'ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server'
    
    engine = sa.create_engine(f'mssql+pyodbc://{server}/{database}?username={username}? 
    password={password}?timeout={timeout}&driver={driver}')
    cn = engine.connect()

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Compliance SQL Backend Reporting")


    HEIGHT = 800
    WIDTH = 1000



    #background image
    canv = tk.Canvas(root, width=80, height=80, bg='white')
    canv.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("NMGC_Emera_color240x75.png"))  # PIL solution
    canv.create_image(20, 20, anchor='nw', image=img)
    
    background_label= tk.Label(root, image=img)
    background_label.place(x=0,y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

    #button Functionaility 

    #def test_function(entry):
    #print("Button Clicked you typed:", entry)



    def test_function(entry):
  
    #sql=tk.StringVar()  
        query = pd.read_sql(f'Select * from [dbo].[{entry}]', con=cn)
        query=tk.StringVar(root, '', query)
        dataframe=pd.DataFrame(query)
        data_entry=tk.Entry(root, textvariable=query)
        data_entry.get()
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
 




    #Guid setup

    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = HEIGHT, width=WIDTH)
    canvas.pack()

    frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#7B94AD', bd=5)
    frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.1, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.1, anchor='n')

    entry = tk.Entry(frame, bg='white')
    entry.place(relwidth=0.65, relheight=1)

    button = tk.Button(frame, text='Generate Report', font = 40, command=lambda: 
    test_function(entry.get())) 
    button.place(relx=0.7, relheight=1, relwidth=0.3)

    lower_frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='#7B94AD', bd=10)
    lower_frame.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.25, relwidth=0.75, relheight=0.6, anchor='n')

    answer_label=tk.Entry(lower_frame, bg='white')
    answer_label.place(relwidth=1, relheight=1)







    root.mainloop()

    Exception in Tkinter callback
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
    File "c:\Users\AAPWP\Desktop\GUI Python\SqlAlchemyConnect.py", line 77, in <lambda>
    button = tk.Button(frame, text='Generate Report', font = 40, command=lambda: 
    test_function(entry.get()))
    File "c:\Users\AAPWP\Desktop\GUI Python\SqlAlchemyConnect.py", line 49, in test_function
    query=tk.StringVar(root, '', query)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 540, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
    File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 368, in __init__
    raise TypeError("name must be a string")
    TypeError: name must be a string
```

Comment: What do you expect this code to do? `tk.StringVar(root, '', query)`

Comment: I had originally put in a text variable in the answer_label but it would not print a previous person told me to put it as a stringvar.  This was my first attempt at a stringvar

Comment: What do you mean it would not print? You can assign the `textvariable` different types of variables like `StringVar` but displaying that information on a `label` doesn't involve printing something.

Comment: I still don't understand what you think that code would do. What do you think the third parameter is used for?

Comment: to answer both of your questions this is how I had it before textvariable=query in my answer_label code and what I was told (still new) was to assign it as a string var and to add the .get in my definition to allow the output to go into the answer_label but I am thinking that I misunderstood what was said

Comment: now I know for sure I am thinking I overthought the response, this is what was said to me "You cannot assign a function reference to textvariable option of a label. Use an instance of StringVar() instead and then update this variable using .set() inside test_function()."

Comment: I am still confused about what you want to do.  Are you just trying to grab a value from an `entry` and then display that value on a `label`?  Your test function is confusing me greatly. What do you need the `query` variable for if you expect to type in the entry and grab the value that was typed? Your question asks about getting a value that was typed into an `entry` but it looks like you tried to set the `entry` value with something you read with `pandas`?

Comment: I might of miss-typed, what the user is going to do is type out a SQL table name in the entry , users table for example, and what I am trying to do is get that table from the database and print it out into a label (the select * statement)